# Alternative synaptics touchpad driver for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have hp pavillion dv6 laptop(Windows 7) with a synaptics touchpad . The gestures like two finger scroll doesn't work automatically after I disabled a startup service or something. (I dont remember properly what I did). But having the synaptics touchpad service enabled during the startup doesn't help. I have to go to the control panels and after clicking on the synaptics control panel icon the gestures start working. Any help here? 
 
          But my real question is something else. I have a Linux Mint Nadia setup in my machine. When I use the gestures in the linux os it is much more smoother and responsive. I guess thats because of better drivers (?). Is there a way I could get the same experience in windows. Like an alternative driver maybe? I'm not very sure about how it all works. Please bear with the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the Synaptics driver isn't the issue - it's some other process disrupting the driver. To find the culprit process, try going to the Resource Monitor to see which processes are running when this issue is occurring. Otherwise, I'd recommend you to look up Synaptics touchpad troubleshooting.

Anyhow, since Synaptics drivers are rarely the problem there are **very** few alternatives. One of them, though, is [two-finger-scroll](https://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/). Note that this application's last commit dates back to February 2009 so there might be issues with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the title/question, but it's worth saying and related to the description you provide "gestures like two finger scroll doesn't work automatically after I disabled a startup service or something. (I dont remember properly what I did). But having the synaptics touchpad service enabled during the startup doesn't help. I have to go to the control panels and after clicking on the synaptics control panel icon the gestures start working. Any help here?", I experienced similar issues with a few laptops, and it was Windows updating the Synaptics driver without my approval. Until I found out, it was a guessing game thinking it was something I've done like modifying a preference or installing/disabling something, it wasn't the case, it was the automatic update.